# How can I set the app to use High Perf GPU instead of the standard one?

Tags: macos, gpu, customization

Can I set the app to Require High Perf GPU? The thing is, I use few apps which in my strong belief should use NVIDIA GPU (which is much better instead the Intel built in graphics) and it uses the built in Intel one? Can I change which application should use the second, better GPU?

I know I can choose which GPU should be used within the actual app, but there is only GPU listed - Intel. I can't choose NVIDIA, as it does not exist on the list within the app. I need to force my Mac to select the second GPU manually somehow.

Thanks for help.
P.

Comment: We need more details. E.g. we have no idea what model of Mac you're using, nor what version of macOS you're running? Also, I should point out that while a dedicated GPU may have better specs, that doesn't mean it's better in all instances or for all apps. For example, MS Word is not going to function better with the dedicated GPU. So, wanting to always have the dedicated GPU selected isn't usually the recommended option (unless you're having issues with the built-in one and need to avoid using it). Perhaps you should also list a couple of the apps you feel should be using the NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: Sure. This is MaacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012). GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GE 650M 1024 MB & Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536MB. There were few apps I am after but the one I need it to be used for is a game Civilization (by Sid Meier) and Photoshop (but not sure will Intel handle that better). In fact, I've just realised that Intel has more memory than NVIDIA, I thought it's opposite.